# Tkinter: Set 0, 0 coords on the bottom of a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

When I usually create a canvas, the (0, 0) coord is place on the top left corner of it. Now I want to set it on the bottom left corner. I think I have to set the "scrollbarregion" but I can't understand how to do it.
Can someone explain?

Comment: you can make point 0,0 to appear at the bottom left, but point 1,1 will always be to the right and below 0,0. Is that ok, or are you wanting the y coordinate to go _up_ from the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, the second one, I need to invert the y basically @Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tkinter canvas does not support changing the coordinate system. You can scroll the canvas so that 0,0 appears in the bottom left corner, but that won't affect the coordinate system. Point (1,1) will always be to the right and below the point (0,0).

From the [official tcl/tk documentation on the canvas](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M9) (tkinter is just a wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter):

> COORDINATES
>
> All coordinates related to canvases are stored as floating-point numbers. Coordinates and distances are specified in screen units, which are floating-point numbers optionally followed by one of several letters. If no letter is supplied then the distance is in pixels. If the letter is m then the distance is in millimeters on the screen; if it is c then the distance is in centimeters; i means inches, and p means printers points (1/72 inch). Larger y-coordinates refer to points lower on the screen; larger x-coordinates refer to points farther to the right. Coordinates can be specified either as an even number of parameters, or as a single list parameter containing an even number of x and y coordinate values.
>
> TRANSFORMATIONS
>
> Normally the origin of the canvas coordinate system is at the upper-left corner of the window containing the canvas. It is possible to adjust the origin of the canvas coordinate system relative to the origin of the window using the xview and yview widget commands; this is typically used for scrolling. Canvases do not support scaling or rotation of the canvas coordinate system relative to the window coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a couple of variables that hold the size of the screen. then replace `(0,0)` with `(self.screenWidth-0, self.sceenHeight-0)`

Comment: Yeah, I used to do this, but I think it could be easier and faster with scrollbarregion

Comment: The advantage of this method is that is you do want something measured from the top left you don't have to do the same in reverse, if that makes sense

Comment: Yeah xD, but I need more often to measure from the bottom, thats why I'm asking.