# Tkinter Canvas Coordnates

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a ball and paddle game and I am confused with the X and Y values of the canvas.

```
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.y = -3
            print ('Pos[3] requirement is met')
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
```

I am currently Wondering where the Origin of the Canvas starts
Thanks!

Comment: Usually the origin is the top-left corner of the window which has the container

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652978/tkinter-set-0-0-coords-on-the-bottom-of-a-canvas#:~:text=Normally%20the%20origin%20of%20the,is%20typically%20used%20for%20scrolling)

Comment: Have you tried using Canvas.canvasx(x) and Canvas.canvasy(y) functions...!?

Comment: Thank You both, You have solved my Problem. After your clarification I was reading the first if statement as the ball's height detection to bounce it down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper-left corner of the canvas is 0,0, assuming you haven't adjusted it via scrolling. Larger y-coordinates refer to points lower on the screen; larger x-coordinates refer to points farther to the right.

If you are needing to translate event coordinates to canvas coordinates you can use the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods. These will translate a window coordinate to the appropriate canvas coordinate.